# Constructing an array of string from the properties of a function return type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typing

I need to create an array containing the properties of the return type of this function

```
const createTableData = (cod: string, promo: string, type: string) => ({
  code: cod,
  promo: promo,
  type: type,
})
```

thus the array should be

```
["code", "promo", "type"]
```

but the compiler complains saying that I'm using the ReturnType as a value here

```
class T extends ReturnType<typeof createTableData> {}
const vals = Object.keys(Reflect.construct(T, []))
```

Comment: The compiler complains, because you are using the ReturnType as a concrete class to inherit from. I might be missing something, but I'm not sure I understood what you are looking for. Do you want to generate a type from the createTableData like so: `type Foo = ["code", "promo", "type"]` or do you want to get the concrete array (which would be something like: `const foo = ["code", "promo", "type"]`)?

Comment: @r3dst0rm the concrete array

Comment: You probably want `class T implements ReturnType<typeof createTableData>` as can be observed [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRAVZAjANogIqsjALwwAUoAJogFwzTwCWYA5gDQwAO8IAtiHqMWHGFACeXOgyjM2ASlIA+CgG84IGpx78QnCVJgBfeQG4AUOeA5kECDHQwmfLnj6IwUewCVEUAK7wYOiSiAA8BoggAGZwSKgY2HiEUMgqquYwMAD02TCI8LzwMFiIwMj+EIjcvFLwUEyI9shIMHxMdiLmRkA).

Comment: So it is not possible to create an array like `["code", "promo", "type"]` starting from the return type of `createTableData`. I need to manually specify all the properties through a class.

Answer (score 0):

To create the type `["code", "promo", "type"]` from `createTableData` you need to do

```
type T = keyof ReturnType<typeof createTableData>
```

However instantiating an array from this type definition is probably not possible. TypeScript only runs during compilation but instantiating is done during runtime. What can be done is instantiating the array explicitly and rely on TypeScript to warn if the API change.

```
const vals: T = ["code", "promo", "type"]
```